# How do I add request parameters in Ember-rest

Tags: ember.js

I am using [ember-rest](https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest) in my application for persistence layer, and it has been working great. One of the resources that I am working with, requires some optional resource parameters. Looking at the ember-rest source code, I couldn’t find anything related to setting request parameters, but it is possible that I overlooked something.

My question is, does ember-rest provide a way to specify request parameters to be appended to the URL? If not, some advice about how I should add this functionality to ember-rest would be very appreciated.

For example, I am working with a resource called *blocki* which comes with the following REST api:

```
POST /api/apps/:app_id/blockies?parent=:parent_id 
    - default :parent_id=:app_id
    - TODO: error if the blocki cannot be placed in :parent_id
PUT /api/blockies/:id
PUT /api/blockies/:id?parent=:parent_id
    - update the blocki and reparent it
DELETE /api/blockies/:id
```

As you can see when I do a `put` request to update this resource I can optionally pass a parent_id if I want to update that. I want to achieve this using ember-rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely customize the url for a resource or resource controller by overriding the [`_resourceUrl()`](https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest/blob/master/src/ember-rest.js#L223) method. For instance:

```
_resourceUrl: function() {
  return this._super() + '?parent=' + this.get('parent_id');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response Dan! Ok, so if I understand correctly I should put the logic in place when I override `_resourceUrl()` to see if the request parameter is available and if so then append those parameters to the URL. Because parent_id does not need to be added to every type of request. is that correct?

Comment: That seems correct for your use case, Aras. By the way, if you need further control over the request, you can also override _resourceRequest() or _prepareResourceRequest() in the Ember.ResourceAdapter mixin (see the comments).